# WPF Two Way Data Binding to Textbox.Text only working in one direction

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My question is not about serialization I am getting the serialization part to work just fine, but for context I am trying to serialize some properties set by the user in a WPF form, and therefore require a two-way binding (which I can only get to work in one direction: target-to-source updates).

Let's say I have defined an application property that is a container for my properties I want to be serializable:

```
public SerializableApplicationProperties ThisAppsSerializableProperties { get; set; }
```

The SerializableApplicationProperties class looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableApplicationProperties
{

    public SerializableApplicationProperties()
    {
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePath = new ObservableString();
    }

    public SerializableApplicationProperties(string defaultFilePath)
    {
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePath = new ObservableString(defaultFilePath);
    }

    public ObservableString UserSelectedPreFillFilePath { get; set; }

}
```

I have one property defined so far that I need to establish a two way-binding for in code (yes, in code). Please do not suggest how I can do this in XAML markup, unless you also explain how to do it entirely in code.

The property is "UserSelectedPreFillFilePath", which you can see is of type "ObservableString".

ObservableString Class looks like this:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class ObservableString : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _stringValue;
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return _stringValue; }
            set
            {
                _stringValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StringValue");
            }
        }

        public ObservableString() { }

        public ObservableString(string value)
        {
            this._stringValue = value;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

A very simple class that holds a "StringValue" property and implements INotifyChange.

So then, I try to establish a two-way binding between this "UserSelectedPreFillFileLocation" and a text box on the main window.

I want a two-way binding so that before I close down the application I can serialize the UserSelectedPreFillFileLocation property (which should be automatically updated based on what the user puts in the textbox in the window).

Then when the application loads from a file (deserializes) that textbox is auto-populated with the UserSelectedPreFillFileLocation value via the binding.

Second to last thing, my converter class definition:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ObservableString), typeof(string))]
class ObservableStringToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableString myVar = (ObservableString)value;
        return myVar.StringValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string myVar = (string)value;
        return new ObservableString(myVar);
    }
}
```

Lastly here is the definition of the binding. The binding works target-to-source but not the other way around. I.E. when the user updates the textbox, UserSelectedPreFillFileLocation is updated, but not the other way around.

```
        Binding UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding = new Binding();
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ThisAppsSerializableProperties.UserSelectedPreFillFilePath));
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.Source = ThisAppsSerializableProperties;          
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.Converter = new ObservableStringToStringConverter();
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        ThisAppInstanceMainWindow.TxtbxPrefillFileLocation.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding);
```

Comment: `UserSelectedPreFillFilePath` needs to raise `PropertyChanged` in its setter. You're not notifying the UI when you replace the value of that property. Alternatively, you can make `UserSelectedPreFillFilePath` a *read-only* ObservableString property, and only set or bind to its `Value` property. P.S. Do the binding in XAML.

Comment: UserSelectedPreFillFilePath does raise property changed in the setter doesn't it? Since it is of type ObservableString (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

Comment: Here is the complete text of the setter for `UserSelectedPreFillFilePath`: `set;`. That's it. That's all you gave us. It's not raising any events, and `SerializableApplicationProperties` doesn't define any events or implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Are you saying the actual code is different from what's in your question?

Comment: Think of it this way: `ObservableString a = null;` How is the setter for `ObservableString.Value` being called there?

Comment: The ObservableString class doesn't define a Value property (unless there is some implicit Value property that's part of every class that I don't know about).

Comment: It does have a StringValue property that raises the PropertyChange when it is set. So my thought was that the converter would translate the ObservableString into a normal string to be used in the text box. When I set the ObservableString.StringValue property via a call to something like UserSelectedPreFillFilePath.StringValue = "Something", I thought that would invoke the PropertyChange Event. Sorry I do not think I am seeing the big picture of what you are saying.

Comment: Whoops, `StringValue` was the one I meant, thanks. You have a reference to type A. You point that reference at a different instance of type A. Why would that call any setters on any properties of the old instance of type A? Worse: If anybody in the UI had put a handler on the PropertyChanged event of the old instance, they're still sitting there waiting for the *old instance* to raise PropertyChanged. If you set StringValue on the new instance, the event will be raised, but nobody will be listening.

Comment: Your idea here comes along every so often. `public ObservableString UserSelectedPreFillFilePath { get; } = new ObservableString()` will work, but you must set `UserSelectedPreFillFilePath.Value` in your viewmodel, and bind to `UserSelectedPreFillFilePath.Value` in the XAML. That's clumsy, but saves you typing in the declaration of `UserSelectedPreFillFilePath`. I don't like sticking `.Value` everywhere. My preferred approach is to use a snippet in VS to create INPC properties.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what I was doing wrong.

I have indeed defined an ObservableString and the observable property that raises the property changed event is the StringValue within the class.

So, in this case I did not even need a converter since the source property I should have defined for the binding was the StringValue, and the source object should have been the UserSelectedPreFillFilePath.

Corrected code that is now working great with the two-way binding:

```
        Binding UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding = new Binding();
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ThisAppsSerializableProperties.UserSelectedPreFillFilePath.StringValue));
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.Source = ThisAppsSerializableProperties.UserSelectedPreFillFilePath;
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        ThisAppInstanceMainWindow.TxtbxPrefillFileLocation.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, UserSelectedPreFillFilePathBinding);
```

Comment: If you're binding to `StringValue`, what's the converter for?  What happens when you assign a new ObservableString object to `UserSelectedPreFillFilePath`, still without notifying anybody of the change? You've only dug yourself in deeper.

Comment: I'm relatively new to WPF and .NET so I don't want to get into an argument or pretend to be an expert, but the change that I made is doing exactly what I expect it to do. Please feel free to post an opposing answer that shows the code for what you would have done differently. I posted in the answer that I removed the converter, so I'm not sure why you asked about the converter. My understanding is that because UserSelectedPreFillFilePath is of type ObservableString (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged) changes are being notified. It is working as is for me.

Comment: My mistake about the converter, I must have misread your answer. What you have here is a fragile workaround.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but if you don't show any code of what you would have done differently, than your critique is just critique, it doesn't help others understand what should be done differently.

Comment: I explained what you should do differently five days ago.